# SharePoint WSS 3.0 calendar is missing events

Tags: sharepoint, events, calendar

I have a WSS 3.0 site at a small school.  The teachers are using the calendar regularly when suddenly, the events are not longer showing up in calendar view.  The events are THERE (if I create an email alert, create an event, I will get a clickable link to the event, but if I view the calendar in IE, no events)  Each months shows *some* events, but it's like the calendar gets 'full' and suddenly there are days with NOTHING.

I read some stuff from MS on increasing the limit for entries, but I don't think it applies because we're no where near 2000 events in the calendar.  I've tooled around the XML files, but nothing is jumping out at me.

There were a couple of MS articles that I ran thru, but no resolution yet.  Any ideas?  Conversely, is there a recommended cloud service that can replace this if it's not functional?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's been a while, I just encountered the same issue, so I thought I'd reply with my fix.

I created a new Calendar View (using the defaults) and all the items showed up. Too simple? I thought so too.  I don't don't why this happened - the original calendar and the new one both had the same values (nothing was filtered, etc.), but the new one shows all the items.

Just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Are the calendar items in a standard list view, but not calendar view? Is this happening across site collections?

If so, I'd recommend rebuilding their MS Office Profile. You can do that from Control Panel>Add or Remove Programs>MS Office Professional Plus. Then select Repair. Reboot, and see if your calendar view is back to normal.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help you with besides answering your question? If your question is answered you may mark it as answered with the checkmark next to it